# Является ли хорошей практикой использования ссылок в цикле foreach для модификации переменных?

Tags: php, foreach, ссылки, хороший-тон

Хорошая ли практика, если модифицировать переменные таким образом:

```
$z = 'z';
$y = 'y';
$x = 'x';
$arr = [ &$z, &$y, &$x ];
foreach( $arr as &$val ){
    $val .= '_1';
}
```

Comment: Ничего плохого в этом нет.

Comment: Ну если такая возможность предоставлена языком, то почему нет?

Comment: Если вам надо обработать массив и изменить элементы, то как еще вы можете это сделать? Либо `$arr[$key]['value'] = ...` либо `&... $val['value']`, второе очевидно короче и удобнее

Comment: teran, спустя 8 месяцев непрерывной практики пришёл к этому же мнению